# Missing Site Page in "Site Pages" Library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sitepages

I am using SharePoint Designer so that I can make copies of a page and reuse it as a template. However the one page I want to use as a template is not showing up in my SharePoint Designer "SitePages" folder. It is showing on the SharePoint site.

Any thoughts as to

- why this may not be showing ?
- how I can duplicate the site for the other sites I need to make?

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was having had to do with how I titled it. I didn't realize that the URL would allow me to include the "&" character, but SharePoint Designer wouldn't read it with that URL. Fixed this issue and it reappeared. Thank you for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

**Why may this not be showing ?**

It depends on the creation source of your page ,

[image]

All pages are not located at site page and it maybe at pages or other document library.

[image]

**How I can duplicate the site for the other sites I need to make?**

If your site is `a team site` you can go to > site setting > Site Action > Save site as template.

[image]

Create a new site > then select your created template at custom section.

[image]